# Cloudera CDH 5.3.0

Tags: cloudera, flume-ng

Can anyone please tell me where cloudera does save flume agent file? Actually, I want to create another flume agents like I want to run two flume agent simultaneously but could not find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In *CDH 5.3.0*, Cloudera has provided a template configuration file named `flume-conf.properties.template` on following path.

```
/etc/flume-ng/conf
```

You can make copy of this file and make changes in this file according to your requirement. If you are unable to find file on that path, then here is a sample Flume Agent configuration file.

```
agent.sources = seqGenSrc
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = loggerSink

# For each one of the sources, the type is defined
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.type = seq

# The channel can be defined as follows.
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.channels = memoryChannel

# Each sink's type must be defined
agent.sinks.loggerSink.type = logger

#Specify the channel the sink should use
agent.sinks.loggerSink.channel = memoryChannel

# Each channel's type is defined.
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory

# Other config values specific to each type of channel(sink or source)
# can be defined as well
# In this case, it specifies the capacity of the memory channel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100
```

flume-ng and flume-ng-agent script files are on following path.

```
/usr/bin/flume-ng
/etc/init.d/flume-ng-agent
```

Comment: i m looking for through cloudera manager where they have provided an agent. I made changes over there and  it is running perfectly. But I cannot add another agent graphically